# Set a Minimum Width for Python Rich Logging (RichHandler)

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab, python-logging, rich

I am using `RichHander` to format log output inside Python.  While this works great locally, when I run inside GitLab, it seems to default to using a terminal that is 80 characters wide.  This makes the output fairly difficult to read and scan quickly.  I would like to change this default width for the RichHandler, but I don't see a way to do it.

**Is there a way to set a minimum console width for the Python RichHandler log handler?**

```py
# Pseudocode:
    
import logging
from rich.logging import RichHandler

def setup_logging():
  logger = logging.getLogger('myLogger')
  richFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
  richHandler = RichHandler()
  # Something like: richHandler.setMinimumWidth(255)
  richHandler.setFormatter(richFormatter)
  logger.addHandler(richHandler)
```

Comment: I think that gitlab is piping the output of locally runned commands and thus, RichHandler defaults to 80 character wide, which I think is pretty standard for a default. As for the original question, I cannot help any further.

Comment: @xcodz-dot That was my assumption as well.  Fixing the output might be easier from the RichHandler side than the GitLab Runner console output side.

Answer (score 4):

Add `console=Console(width=255)` to the handler constructor.

E.g.

```
from rich.console import Console
richHandler = RichHandler(console=Console(width=255))
```